# Error When Executing mongod Command in Window 10

Tags: mongodb

In this problem, when I tried to execute mongod command to establish connection to db server. However, the error has been displayed as bellow.

[[here is the error when I executed mongod command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dQUZ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAfoW.jpg)

[here is the rest of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XH5g.jpg)

I have already installed mongo successfully, created data/db folder, tried to search some references that suggested removing lock file and restarting MongoDB service. But, they do not work.

Here is the full error message:

```
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.606+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23
285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable T
LS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.608+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":49
15701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"i
ncomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInterna
lClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0
,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.612+07:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22
601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterfa
ce startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.612+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":46
48602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.614+07:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22
601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterfa
ce startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.614+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":51
23008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr"
:{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.614+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":51
23008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr"
:{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipi
ents"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.615+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":59
45603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.616+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":46
15611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":4280,"port":
27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-KMNS09Q"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.617+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23
398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","at
tr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.617+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23
403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"
5.0.14","gitVersion":"1b3b0073a0b436a8a502b612f24fb2bd572772e5","modules":[],"al
locator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","targ
et_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.617+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51
765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Micr
osoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19043)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.618+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21
951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"option
s":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.620+07:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20
557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","
attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only
 directory: C:\\data\\db\\"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.620+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":47
84900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for
 shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.621+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":47
84901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.621+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":47
84902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.621+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20
562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.621+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":47
84905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.621+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":47
84906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.622+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20
520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisi
tions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.622+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":47
84918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.622+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":47
84921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.622+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22
582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress
activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.623+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":47
84923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.623+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":47
84925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.623+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":47
84927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.623+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":47
84928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.624+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":47
84929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.624+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":47
84931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.624+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":47
84926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.624+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20
565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.625+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23
138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

What can be the reason here? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: _{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-18T12:32:39.620+07:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","
attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only
 directory: C:\\data\\db\\"}}_  Perhaps `mongod` does not have write permission for `C:\data\db`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, Done!!. Thanks a lot for pointing to me about that. Best regards. 